A Science fiction movie where a scientist hires AI programmer. With human patients with mental trauma
I'm trying to remember the name of a movie. 
In the movie a male scientist working in a facility which appears to be government funded interviews a female AI programmer and tests an AI she wrote by asking it questions.
The facility takes care of patients and does something to them to help with mental issues. The patients appear to be unable to talk to the non-patients but can secretly communicate with each other.
They do a theory of mind test on a guy who underwent such treatment. I think the movie was released some time after 2010 and before 2017.

Please refrain from tagging this question with tags for entirely unrelated films that this question isn't about.

You're looking for The Machine

Two artificial intelligence engineers come together as they work to create the first ever self-aware artificial intelligence. A veteran AI engineer secretly hopes to develop technology to help his diseased daughter, even if it means funding comes from the powerful Ministry of Defence (MoD). His new partner, a young woman gifted in the field of AI, is brought on after her breakthroughs are recognized by the MoD. Things go wrong when the MoD takes over and advances the researchers' work to the next level, teaching the AI to kill and follow MoD instructions with its new and nearly indestructible body.




